# Perl - Unable to create class variable for child class

Tags: perl

I am creating a child class having base class as [`Net::SSH2`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSSH2). when I am trying to add a class variable I am getting error saying -

> Not a HASH reference at F:\temp\fooA.pl line 17.

If I do the same thing wihtout `Net::SSH2` then it works fine.

Here is the code :

```
use strict;

my $x = Foo->new();

package Foo;

use base qw (Net::SSH2);

sub new {
    my ($class, %args) = @_;

    my $self = $class->SUPER::new(%args);
    $self->{'key'} = 'value';
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple: Net::SSH2 doesnt return a hash ref, but a blessed scalar:

```
use Scalar::Util qw(reftype);
print reftype($self) . "\n";  # SCALAR
```

BTW: It's always dangerous to rely on implementation details of third party code.

A possible solution would be to use inside out objects:

```
package Foo;

use Scalar::Util qw( refaddr );
use base qw( Net::SSH2 );

my %keys;

sub new {
    my ( $class, %args ) = @_;

    my $self = $class->SUPER::new ( %args );

    $keys{ refaddr ( $self ) } = 'value';

    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}
```

Comment: ... or just `$self->{'super'} = $class->SUPER::new(%args)`